# Python saving array to csv file

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am trying to save an array to a csv file with the code below:

```
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(dvds)
```

The array is:

```
dvds = ["monsters inc","terminator genisys","taken","taken 2","taken 3","ted","ted 2","world war z","hitman"]
```

But when the file is generated it separates each letter individually into separate columns. Here is the link to download my [output.csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bylw2lOzb9kBakdFeWZ2YTBVQ3M/view?usp=sharing)

I expected to get 1 movie title in one column instead of having the title of the movie spread out into multiple columns. When you download the file above you will see what I mean.

Please let me know what I can do to fix the problem.

Comment: Please add the output that you got and the expected behavior on the question itself.

Comment: you can download the output file just click on the link

Comment: You should include the file directly instead of including a downlad link. Also the site looks very scam to me.

Comment: I changed the link to google drive

Comment: You need to include more code. What does dvds contain?

Comment: I added the array :)

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be helping to raise your content quality

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `writerows` expects a list of rows. Each row should be a sequence, one element per column.

You will get the same unwanted behaviour by writing:

```
writer.writerow("monsters inc")
#instead of
writer.writerow(["monsters inc"])
```

This happens because it tries to split the row into columns and the only way in this case is one letter per column

Try changing your input list like this

```
dvds = [["monsters inc"],["terminator genisys"],["taken"],["taken 2"],["taken 3"],["ted"],["ted 2"],["world war z"],["hitman"]]
```

This could be done like

```
dvd_rows = [[dvd] for dvd in dvds]
```